# How to make the position of Widget fix?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, widget

I am creating a widget on click the button. The widget is appearing at center of the screen. I want to show that widget at a proper predefined position of the screen. And when ever I open that widget it should show at that point only. How to do this not able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QWidget::move()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#pos-prop) function before you show it.